# Unwanted Text Shadow Displaying Text Pre-Hover

Tags: css, sass

I have a feed-reader that displays text on hover. Before hovering, some text shadow is present, making the word shadow visible.

http://codepen.io/Teeke/pen/JWqpoP

```
 a{
        color: inherit;
        text-decoration: none;
   }
```

I've tried changing line 109 in the CSS from

```
'color: inherit'
```

to transparent, or rgba(0,0,0,0), but that will make all the text disappear.

How can I fix this CSS conflict?

Comment: You need do something like this? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BWeYQm

Comment: That's OK Christian, but taking the shadow away completely makes the text hard to read on hover. Shadow needs to be present on hover, and invisible pre-hover. Must be some conflicting classes, but I don't know where.

Comment: The `text-shadow` on line 83 in the `.item` class selector is what's causing it. Maybe you can move that to the hover state?

Comment: Just wondered how you traced that Ken H. Inspect Element is hard to use on hoverable items. Do you have a specific technique to know what CSS is acting on each element, or do you find it by eye?

Answer (score 1):

So, basically what you need to do is originally set the text shadow's color to transparent. Then, when it is hovered over, you can change the text shadow's color to whatever you want. Here's an example of what this effect looks like on text that's already visible:

```css
h1 {
  color: red;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 3px transparent;
}

h1:hover {
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #333;
}
```

```html
<h1>Hello world</h1>
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: @RubyRube No problem! Would you mind marking my answer as correct if it works?

Comment: I'll try it tomorrow, and see which answer works best. :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like making this change to the SCSS code:

```
&:hover{
  .bar, .overlay{
    transform: translateY(0);
    color: inherit;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #222;
  }
```

and removing the `text-shadow` from the `.item` selector also works.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to change your font to `transparent` to fade an element like that. Besides just being a bad practice and pain in the butt to work with, it isn't performant. Just fade the entire `.bar` and `.overlay` from `opacity: 0` to `opacity: 1` on hover

```js
var Settings = {
  subreddit : 'PositiveTechnology',
  after: 'o',
  limit: 25
}

let d = new Date; document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = d.toUTCString();;

let $grid = $('#positive-technology')
  .attr('data-loading-text','')
  .packery({ itemSelector: '.item' })
  .on('click','.overlay', function(){
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('active').parent().packery('layout');
  });

function RedditJSON(){  
  this.loadLink = function(){
    Settings.isLoading = true;
    return 'https://www.reddit.com/r/' + Settings.subreddit + '/.json?after=' + Settings.after + '&limit=' + Settings.limit;
  }
  
  this.next = function(feed){
    if (Settings.theLast) return;
    if (feed.data.after == null) Settings.theLast = true;
    let posts = feed.data.children;
    for(let i = 0; i < posts.length; i++){
      if(true){ // posts[i].data.post_hint == 'image' || posts[i].data.url.search('imgur')
        if(!posts[i].data.hasOwnProperty('preview')) continue;
        
        let image = posts[i].data.preview.images[0];
        let permalink = 'https://reddit.com' + posts[i].data.permalink;
        
        let elem    = $('<div>').addClass('item').css('background-image', 'url(' + image.source.url + ')');
        let overlay = $('<a>').addClass('overlay').appendTo(elem);
        let bar     = $('<div>').addClass('bar').appendTo(elem);
        let link    = $('<a>').addClass('post').attr({target: '_blank', href: permalink}).appendTo(bar).text(posts[i].data.title);
        let zoom    = $('<a>').addClass('zoom').attr({target: '_blank', href: image.source.url}).appendTo(bar).html('<i class="fa fa-camera-retro"></i>');
        
        if (posts[i].data.stickied){
          elem.addClass('stickied');
        }
        
        // if (image.source.width > image.source.height){
        //   elem.addClass('wide');
        // }
        
        // if(posts[i].data.created % 6 == 0){
        //   elem.addClass('active');
        // }
        
        $grid.append(elem).packery('appended', elem).packery('layout');
      }
    }
    
    Settings.after = feed.data.after;
    Settings.isLoading = false;
  }
}

var bob = new RedditJSON();

function loadNext(){
  if (Settings.isLoading){
    setTimeout(loadNext,100);
    return;
  } else {
    $.getJSON(bob.loadLink(), bob.next);
  }
}

$(function() {
  // return;
  loadNext();
  $(window).scroll(function () {    
    console.log($(window).scrollTop() + ' ' + ($('body').height() - $(window).height() - 10));
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $('body').height() - $(window).height() - 10 && !Settings.isLoading) {
      loadNext();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
/* https://designshack.net/articles/css/12-fun-css-text-shadows-you-can-copy-and-paste/ */
@import url("http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:200,300, 800");
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin-top: 100px;
  padding: 0;
  background: #181818;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  color: rgba(250, 250, 250, 0.8);
  background: url("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/577362/pexels-photo%20(4).jpg");
  background-size: 100% 90%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(100, 100, 120, 0.8);
}

.base-title {
  font-weight: 200;
  font-size: 85px;
  /* ORIG 70px */
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: lighter;
}

h4 {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin-top: -10%;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#date {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 10%;
}

.ticker {
  margin-top: 7%;
}

.grid {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
}
.grid::after {
  display: block;
  content: attr(data-loading-text);
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
}
.grid .item {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #000000;
  -webkit-filter: saturate(1.5) contrast(107%);
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #222;
}
.grid .item.wide {
  width: 25%;
}
.grid .item.active {
  width: 25%;
  height: 600px;
}
.grid .item.wide.active {
  width: 100%;
  height: 650px;
}
.grid .item .bar {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 4px;
  z-index: 4;
  color: white;
}
.grid .item .bar a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.grid .item .bar a.zoom {
  float: right;
}
.grid .item .overlay {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #001, transparent 100px);
  z-index: 3;
}
.grid .item .bar, .grid .item .overlay {
  transition: transform 250ms, opacity 250ms;
  transform: translateY(80px);
  opacity: 0;
}
.grid .item:hover .bar, .grid .item:hover .overlay {
  transform: translateY(0);
  opacity: 1;
}
.grid .item.stickied .overlay {
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #0f0, transparent 80px);
}
@media (max-width: 520px) {
  .grid .item {
    width: 100% !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/packery@2/dist/packery.pkgd.js"></script>

<h1 class="base-title">Positive Technology</h1>
<!-- <h4>Useful News</h4> -->
<h1 class="ticker"> · Hydroponics · Aeroponics · Micro-solar · Micro-wind · 3D-Printing · Eco-Houses · Water Filtration ·</h1>
<div class="grid" id="positive-technology"></div>
<h2 id="date"></h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got some interesting tips from everybody's answers here, but I went the easiest route. I had some code in the body section of the CSS:

```
text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(100,100,120,0.8);
```

affecting all the text throughout the page. I removed it from body and inserted it into each individual selector as needed.